# Pause and resume a c++ function

Tags: c++, resume, pause

I'm facing a problem in programmation where I did not find any convenient and fast execution solutions.

I'm trying to implement some kind of state machine : take one byte in entry, process it, change state, loop, etc... The purpose is to process byte stream without requiring any memory buffer (processing byte per byte).

The class should looks like this :

```
class Decoder {
  void next() {
    int i = 0;
    std::cout << i << "\n";
    i++;
    yield(); // pseudo code => should stop the function and save the current state (or simply not freeing allocated variables)
    std::cout << i << "\n";
  }
};

Decoder decoder = Decoder();
decoder.next(); // print 1
std::cout << "1.5" << "\n"; // print 1.5
decoder.next(); // print 2
```

A solution could be to create a `step` property to save the step and then resume with a switch but the performances would be strongly impacted. I would like to know if there is a way to exit the execution of a function and then resume it later ?

To be clear, I don't want to pause the entire program, only a function. Pausing such a function would return to the caller and continue the execution of the program until the next `next` is called.

Moreover, I would like to avoid thread and std as much (I prefer all environnements code). Finally, if you have any other alternatives to my problem : process byte stream efficiently for the memory, I'm open to your suggestions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: _To be clear, I don't want to pause the entire program, only a function._ So, in other words, you want threads (`std::thread`)?

Comment: The term you are missing in your question is co-routine. There is no built-in way (yet), but the boost library has an implementation of a co-routine framework.

Comment: "I would like to avoid ... std"? Why? You do know that the standard library is *portable* and all conforming C++ compilers should implement all of it (making it available to all "environments"). Not using the standard library and reinventing the wheel will make you practically a one-man shop with little experience for possible employers.

Comment: As @AlgirdasPreidžius mentioned, you can use a thread and control execution with some kind of synchronization mechanism like a `std::condition_variable`.

Comment: Wow, really fast answers. Thanks to all. So I would like to avoir std, boost etc, because the code is intended to work on IOT device (low memory: SRAM, FLAH, etc...). std and boost are primary intended to work with os and are really limited on such devices. The co-routine, is the term I was searching, you're right. I'm just searching how I could implement them in a simple way.

Comment: To avoid switch you can split method into two and store function pointer to part after `yield`. Saving state will require some buffer either way.

Comment: @ValentinRichard On small processors this is usually achieved by making use of interrupts. Also FreeRTOS supports co-routines.

Comment: That's a good enough reason. But it should probably be mentioned in the question body. It depends on the platform chosen of course, some IoT platforms are more powerful and have more memory then the systems I learned C++ on over 20 years ago. :)

Comment: Can you not just use a state enum and case-switch on it upon entry?   I will read teh question over again, I suspect that I don't understand it well:(

Comment: I'm not a professional c++ programmer, I'm here to learn. @user0042 I'll check that in more details. Could any of you explain how to implement a co--routine ? Does the lib (boost for example), save the state in a buffer or does it play with the stack ? In my point of view an optimal solution could be to create a separate stack for the `next` method and only freeing it at the true end of its execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could achieve just that using these two ways:

**Option 1: Member state**

Split the state machine object into a separate object, and convert all your local variables to members.

For each step of the way, save a `State` member, signifying where are you now throughout the execution of your program.

Each time you enter `next()` check your state against a switch and call the designated inner method for that step.

Each such step method simulates code execution between to consecutive `yields`.

```
struct Decoder {
  void next() {
    switch (_step) {
      case s1:
        step1();
        _step = s2;
        return;

      case s2:
        step2();
        _step = s1;
        return;

      default:
        return; // handle error...
    }
  }

private:
  enum Step { s1, s2 };

  Step _step = s1;
  int _i = 1;

  void step1() {
    std::cout << _i << "\n";
    _i++;
  }

  void step2() {
    std::cout << _i << "\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  Decoder decoder = Decoder();
  decoder.next(); // print 1
  std::cout << "1.5" << "\n"; // print 1.5
  decoder.next(); // print 2
}
```

**Option 2: Thread and signalling**

Use a thread, which you could of course run using native APIs (e.g. pthread_create on POSIX platforms).

Inside your thread, every time you want to `yield`, wait on a conditional variable, e.g:

```
struct Decoder {
  Decoder() {
    _thread = std::thread { &Decoder::worker, this };
  }

  ~Decoder() {
    _thread.join();
  }

  void next() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    _work = true;
  }

private:
  void wait() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    _cond.wait(lock, [this](){return _work;});
  }

  void worker() {
    wait();

    int i = 0;
    std::cout << i << "\n";
    i++;

    wait();

    std::cout << i << "\n";  
  }

  std::thread _thread;
  std::mutex _mutex;
  std::condition_variable _cond;
  bool _work = false;
};

int main() {
  Decoder decoder;
  decoder.next(); // print 1
  std::cout << "1.5" << "\n"; // print 1.5
  decoder.next(); // print 2
}
```